# Write databricks df to azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I'm using Azure Databricks and I want a dataframe to be written to azure blob storage container. This is my current code.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.sarcscdataplatform.dfs.core.windows.net", "<storage-account-key>")

source_table = "dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/fan_enhanced"
destination_path = "abfss://gold-container@sarcscdataplatform.dfs.core.windows.net/output.csv"
dbutils.fs.cp(source_table, destination_path, recurse=True)
```

It creates the file but it is always empty while there is data in the dataframe. I look forward to everyones answers and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.sarcscdataplatform.dfs.core.windows.net", "<storage-account-key>")

output_container_path = ""abfss://gold-container@sarcscdataplatform.dfs.core.windows.net" % (output_container_name, storage_name)
output_blob_folder = "%s/data_folder" % output_container_path


# write the dataframe as a single file to blob storage
(dataframe
 .coalesce(1)
 .write
 .mode("overwrite")
 .option("header", "true")
 .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
 .save(output_blob_folder))
```

Comment: Do you also know how i can name the file? now its in a directory called data_folder and the filename is something like this part-00000-tid-4767984679266576049-5a4052.

Comment: use .save as .save("/path/mydata.csv")